# Groupby custom function based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains survey responses by country.

```
country=['Country A','Country A','Country A','Country B','Country B','Country B']
responses=['Agree','Neutral','Disagree','Agree','Neutral','Disagree']
num_respondents=[10,50,30,58,24,23]
example_df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": country, "Response": responses, "Count": num_respondents})
```

For each country, I want to compute the fraction (#Agree-#Disagree)/(Total Respondents). Is there a clean way to do this using groupby or another pandas function?

Comment: The example is not very good it gives 0

Comment: how so? for country A, the result should be (10-30)/(10+30+50) and for country B, the result should be (58-23)/(58+24+23).

Comment: Where is count involved in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps:

```
example_df.groupby('Country').apply(lambda x: (sum(x['Count'][x['Response'] == 'Agree']) 
                                            - sum(x['Count'][x['Response'] == 'Disagree'])) 
                                              /sum(x['Count']))
```